# deploying SSIS package with script in 2012

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

The package containing the script was created using VS 2008, but the server where it is going only has the VS 2010 PowerShell.  I am able to Build the script without errors and was tested locally and ran fine. The error is:

> ```
> Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [111]]: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Script Component" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
> ```

Comment: Hi, I think you have some terms mixed up in your question-could you clear it up before you get downvoted. Visual Studio 2008 has the business intelligence developer studio (BIDS) component to edit, test and run SSIS packages targeting SQL Server 2008 and 2008R2. Visual Studio 2010 has a component SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) which is the successor to BIDS. SSDT can edit SQL Server 2012 packages. You will not be able to run (dtexec) a 2008 SSIS package on a server that does not have SQL Server 2012 installed.

Answer (score 2):

The SSIS package deployment has changed in SQL Server 2012.  There is a well-written, step-by-step [blog](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2450/ssis-package-deployment-model-in-sql-server-denali-part-1-of-2/) post that shows you how to deploy an SSIS package to the Integration Services server.  There is also a summary of the SSIS deployment changes in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522534%28SQL.110%29.aspx).

SSDT is the development tool in SQL Server 2012 (rather than BIDS as it was in previous versions), that is used to create SSIS packages.  I have [blogged](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/?s=SSDT) about SSDT in general as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this fixed.

After opening up the project I changed the Build dropdown under the menu tool bar from Debug to Release. When I selected build I got an error:

> Task could not find "sgen.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the
>   registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool
>   exists in the correct processor specific location under the
>   SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

Although I had the correct SDK installed the sgen.exe file was missing. I attempted to install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (version 7.1) but it failed on the 2008 server. I installed it on my Windows 7 PC and copied the sgen.exe from my PC to the build server  to the

`\\vpdr1\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`

I opened the project, edited the script, set to release and was able to build and save. No red X and the SSIS package now works!

Comment: You can edit your other answer and add this one David. Keeps everything well-organized that way :-)